# Which persistence mode is Redis using in Swisscom AppCloud?

Tags: cloud-foundry, swisscomdev

Is it RDB or AOF? I couldn't find any information on this on the wiki or scapp-console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are used. AOF is used for general persistence and RDB for backups.